# How to fix "redirected you too many times."

Tags: php, cookies

I was created simple login and register system and have some issue. But not sure is it with cookie or cookie and php. My code is next:

On index.php ( login page i have this code in header ):

```
<?php
include('includes/config.php');
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($user->login($username,$password)){ 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: home.php');
    exit;

} else {
    $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
}
}
?>
```

And on home page when user is successfully logged in:

```
<?php include('includes/config.php'); 
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

Config file:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','pass');
define('DBNAME','db_name');

define('DIR','http://example.com/');
define('SITEEMAIL','noreply@domain.com');

try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
exit;
}
include('classes/user.php');
include('classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
$user = new User($db);
?>
```

Problem is next, when user successfully logged in and redirected to home page, when user is log out everything is fine, but when user logged in and without log out go back to index page ( log in page ) i get this error:

**This page isn’t working website.com redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

And when i clear my cookie from google chrome browser, error is fixed but user must login again and when same step do again i get again same error.

Comment: well if they are not logged in you send them to the same page that checks and sends them to the same page ad infinitum. What are you expecting here?

Comment: Try reading this and their solutions if you are on wordpress. https://kinsta.com/blog/err_too_many_redirects/

Comment: Im not using Wordpress @Roshan

Comment: And i can't delete cookie every time when i get error, i need to fix this error. Every user who logged in and do this they will get same error as me. @Roshan

Comment: If they're not logged in, the index page should redirect them to the login page. The login page should not include the index page, since the index page should only be visible after you login.

Comment: You shouldn't check the session variable when `$_POST['submit']` is set. They're in the process of logging in, so you don't want to redirect them until after you check the password.

Comment: It's actually a loop on two `if statements` in `index.php` and `home.php` since you set the session on login. Try to use session on `if statements` like `if( isset($_SESSION['username'];))`

Comment: Yes, but when user is logged in successfully, then they will be redirected to home page ( home.php ). And then when logged in user want without logout see login page there is error. @Barmar

Comment: The login page should redirect them to home page if they're already logged in. The home page should redirect to login page if they're not logged in. The script that checks the username and password should not do any redirects until after it checks them. If they give a correct password, it goes to home page, otherwise it goes back to login page.

Answer (score 0):

You should break this up into three scripts, with the following logic:

Home page (and all other content pages): If they're not logged in, it redirects to the login page.

Login page: If they're already logged in, redirect to the home page.

Password checker: This is the action of the login form on the login page. It checks the username and password. If they're correct, it sets the session variable that says that the user is logged in, and redirects to home page. If they're not correct, it redirects back to the login page.

Comment: Im not sure that i write code properly right now... I don't get error for redirection now but login form is displayed logged in users on login page while they are logged in

Comment: I can't tell what you're doing wrong. The logic is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was on index page ( login page ):

**OLD code**

```
if( $user->is_logged_in()){ 
    header('Location: index.php'); --> THIS IS WHERE PROBLEM IS
}
```

**NEW code**

```
if( $user->is_logged_in()){ 
    header('Location: home.php'); // Work correctly
}
```